# Change default button from "Commit" to "Commit and Push" in Source Control view of VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

As mentioned in the title, Is it possible to change the action of that BIG Button that says `Commit` to `Commit and Push`? That way, I need not do one additional action i.e. `push` every time I make a commit.

[image]

Comment: The Git extension allows to set a Post Commit command to 'push'. This changes your default button to 'Commit & Push'. Go to Settings -> Extension -> Git -> Post Commit Command

Comment: bam! mind putting it as an answer.. command is `"git.postCommitCommand": "push"`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The Git extension allows to set a Post Commit command. Which changes the wanted big button to 'Commit & Push' :)

Navigate there and set it to 'push':

> Settings -> Extension -> Git -> Post Commit Command

Or change it in you settings.json:

> "git.postCommitCommand": "push"

[image: PostCommitCommand]
[image]

Comment: This is a very helpful setting, although in my opinion the name is misleading. Surprisingly, this does not take away the "Commit" option, it just makes "Commit & Push" the default. The button actually gets renamed as well.

Comment: Settings are located under: `CTRL+SHIFT-P`, `Preferences: Open User Settings`. Once there you can search for `Post Commit Command` to avoid lots of scrolling.